# How to add category dynamic field with textbox in admin form magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, fieldsets, ui, addfield

[image]

**Add Field in ui Form category selected in check box then display textbox for that category**

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module create :

`src/app/code/VENDOR_PROJECT/Category/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="price_view_customer_groups">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VENDOR_PROJECT\Category\Sources\CustomerGroupOptions</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer groups</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is an exemple with a multiselect field, but you can replace with the standard syntax for checkbox it will work.

Something like this

```
    <field name="activate" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Activate</label>
            <dataScope>activate</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

And obviously you need to have an attribute to save this value.